# Is Visual Studio 2012 compatible with SQL Server 2012 sp1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So, basically I have a Visual Studio 2012 project which is connected to SQL Server 2012 database. Database administrator is moving database to SQL Server 2012 **sp1**. Are there any known issues between Visual Studio 2012 and Sql Server 2012 **sp1**?? I can not seem to find anything on google.

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are they installed on the same machine? SQL server does include a VS shell for some of the reporting and analytics. Or do you just mean a SQL client connection?

Comment: He added `C#` in his tags - so I guess he talks about the .NET version.

Answer (score 4):

*Visual Studio* has nothing to do with the SQL Server version. I guess you want to know whether there are incompatibilities between any *.NET version* and SQL Server 2012 SP1 - and there are not as far as I know. Only if your software was meant for an earlier version of SQL Server and you used deprecated features that have been removed in 2012 you will run into problems.

You need to understand that Visual Studio != .NET!

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only problem that I know of is between VS2008 and SQL Server 2012. This does not address your concern but if you were to create any Windows Mobile projects, you wouldn't be able to connect to SQL Server 2012 through ado.net.

My suggestion is to set up a test instance of Server 2012 and do some testing.